# Using scrapy to get content length of a lists of links

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

As the title indicates, I am interested to know if scrapy can be used to process a list of url's ( url's are stored in a mysql database ).
The only thing i need for each URL is the content-length of the data returned.
Anybody worked on similar projects ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In a callback yield a [`Request`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects) with `method='head'`. In the next callback extract header `HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH` from the [`response`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#response-objects) object.